# Google Compute Engine instance restarts when I ssh

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, google-compute-engine

I have a deep learning vm setup on google cloud platform. I ssh into by clicking the ssh button in my list of vm instances. The problem I am having is that if I run a program and close the ssh window while it is still running, when I ssh back into the vm, the program has been interrupted and the whole vm essentially has restarted.

Is there a way to setup my vm so that I can run a program and then close the ssh connection without it restarting the vm? I want to be able to run programs without being required to leave the ssh window open and my computer on.

Comment: How are you running the program? Normally processes belonging to your SSH session's shell will get a hang-up signal when you close the connection, and their input and output pipes close, and in general they will terminate. Unless you run them with screen or nohup that is, or there are probably more ways to do this. Is that your problem?

Comment: @Rup Thank you so much. Being new to the whole SSH thing, I didn't know it was its own shell that terminates when closed. The "nohup" command did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

As @Rup pointed out, processes belonging to your SSH session's shell will get a hang-up signal when you close the connection. To bypass the hang-up signal and let a program continue running, use the nohup command. Here is an example

```
nohup python test.py &
```

That will run the program test.py and as well as ignore the hang-up signal. The programs output will be stored in a nohup.out file.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!